# React :How to change state inside callback?

Tags: reactjs

As title.
What would I do to change state inside a callback function if I need to change state after I got some results from the back-end or files ,etc...?
Like this:

```
var strView="";
var CountIsPrime=function(InputNum){
    IsPrime(InputNum,function(Res){
        strView=Res;
    });
};
export class TrialClass extends React.Component{
    state={
        DisplayString:strView
    };
    render(){
        return <div>
               <label>{strView}</label>
               <button onclick={()=>CountIsPrime(Math.floor(Math.Random()*10000))}></button>
               </div>
    }
}
```

I am wondering how to change the value inside the label when I call CountIsPrime function?

Answer (score 0):

## Issues

1. `strView` isn't part of any React component state or props, so no amount of updating it will trigger a rerender to display updated values.
2. `onclick` might've been a typo, but it isn't valid.

## Solution

1. Move the `CountIsPrime` callback definition into the component so it can update the state.
2. Render the state value into the label.
3. Use `onClick` handler.

Code

```
export class TrialClass extends React.Component{
  state = {
    strView: '',
  };

  countInPrime = inputNum => IsPrime(
    inputNum,
    strView => this.setState({ strView }),
  );

  render() {
    const { strView } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <label>{strView}</label>
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => this.countInPrime(Math.floor(Math.Random() * 10000))}
        >
          X
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```